# The method getInstance(Context) in the type EasyTracker is not applicable

Tags: android, google-analytics

I`m trying to track an OnClick event with google analytics like that:

```
ImageView info = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent info = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Odot.class);
        startActivity(info);

        EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);
        easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
            .createEvent(
                "UI Action", // Event category (required)
                "Button Pressed", // Event action (required)
                "play", // Event label
                 null) // Event value
            .build()
         );

            }
        });
```

and getting the error:

```
The method getInstance(Context) in the type EasyTracker is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})
```

whats the problem? Sorry for questions like that, I`m learning...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one solution two lines above the problem: `getApplicationContext()`.

Generally, to refer to the parent of an inner class, use `ParentClassName.this` instead of `this` which refers to the inner class instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `this` when you are in an inner class, you will refer to that inner class (in your code `new View.OnClickListener(){}`).

If you are inside an Activity (I think its your case) you should call `ActivityClass.this`. In this way you will refer to the instance of the activity (passing the context the activity is using.). Otherwise you can pass the context returned with `getApplicationContext()`